# Property related to the Krull dimension of modules which form an exact sequence

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, krull-dimension

This is a claim from matsumura's commutative ring theory given in the proof of dimension theorem, and I confused about it for a while:

Given a finite generated module $M,M',M''$over noetherian ring $R$ suppose we have exact sequence
$$0\longrightarrow M'\overset{i}{\longrightarrow} M\overset{j}{\longrightarrow} M''\longrightarrow 0$$ I know by the exactness of localization $\mathrm{Supp}(M)=\mathrm{Supp}(M')\cup\mathrm{Supp}(M'')$, but the author subsequently deduces from it that:
$$\mathrm {dim }M = \max (\mathrm{dim} M’, \mathrm {dim }M'')$$ I know  $\mathrm{dim}M=\mathrm{dim }\mathrm{Supp}(M)$ i.e the length of maximal strictly ordered chain in $\mathrm {Supp}(M)$ but I can figure out why the chain completely lies in supp(M') or supp(M''). Did I misunderstand something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall $\mathrm{Supp}(M)=\{\mathfrak{p} \text{ prime ideal in }A\mid M_{\mathfrak{p}}\neq 0\}$.

Now observe that $$\mathrm{Supp}(M)=\mathrm{Supp}(M')\cup \mathrm{Supp}(M'').$$

Let $\mathfrak{p}_0\subset\cdots\subset \mathfrak{p}_n$ be a maximal chain of prime ideals in $\mathrm{Supp}(M)$.

Assume $M'_{\mathfrak{p}_s}\neq 0$ for all $s=0,\dots, n$. Then $\mathfrak{p}_0\subset\cdots\subset \mathfrak{p}_n$ is a chain of prime ideals in $\mathrm{Supp}(M')$. So $n=\dim M\leq \dim M'$.

On the other hand, assume $M'_{\mathfrak{p}_s}= 0$ for some $s=0,\dots, n$. (Then $M''_{\mathfrak{p}_s}\neq 0$.)

Assume $s$ is the largest such. Now observe that $M'_{\mathfrak{p}_r}= 0$ for $r\leq s$, since $M'_{\mathfrak{p}_r}$ is a localization of $M'_{\mathfrak{p}_s}$. Hence $M''_{\mathfrak{p}_t}\neq 0$ for $t\leq s$.

So we get a chain  $\mathfrak{p}_{0}\subset\cdots\subset \mathfrak{p}_s$ in $\mathrm{Supp}(M'')$ and $\mathfrak{p}_{s+1}\subset\cdots\subset \mathfrak{p}_n$ in $\mathrm{Supp}(M')$.

Now observe that if $M''_{\mathfrak{p}_{t}}=0$ for some $t>s$, then $M''_{\mathfrak{p}_{r}}=0$ for all $r\leq t$. But that is impossible, since $M''_{\mathfrak{p}_{s}}\neq 0$.

So we get that $M''_{\mathfrak{p}_{t}}\neq 0$ for all $t>s$. So the whole chain
$\mathfrak{p}_{0}\subset\cdots\subset \mathfrak{p}_n$ is entirely in $\mathrm{Supp}(M'')$.

This implies $\dim M=\max (\dim M', \dim M'')$.

Comment: sorry could you elaborate on it a little bit, I know supp(M) are prime ideals containing M's annihilator and hence M has a non-trivial localization on it, but for dimension it means the length of the longest chain in it, why it is not possible the longest chain lies partly in Supp M' and partly in Supp M''?

Comment: Added explanation. Essential elementary observation, as you will no doubt notice is that if a localization of a module at a larger prime ideal is 0, then its localization at a small prime ideal is also 0.

Comment: Is this fact also true without The assumption of The modules being finitely generated ?

Answer (score 0):

Let $N$ be a finitely generated $R$-module and $q\subseteq p$ two prime ideals with $q\in Supp(N)$. Since $q_p\in Supp(N_p)$ and $$(N_p)_{q_p}\simeq N_q\neq0$$ we must have necessarily $N_p\neq0$, that is, $p\in Supp(N)$.

From this and $Supp(M)=Supp(M')\cup Supp(M'')$ we conclude that any chain of prime ideals in $Supp(M)$ lies completely in $Supp(M')$ or $Supp(M'')$ and vice-versa.